# Excel datasheet in gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is there anyway we can display excel editable datasheet into GridView (not export)? So users can edit them on-fly. Any 3rd party controls also fine for this option.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) component is exactly what you are looking for.  Otherwise, using Skydrive or some other service is also an option too, if that would work for you.